# I want to hide EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have three `EditText`, in certain conditions, I need to hide the second `EditText`.

But after I hide the second, there is an empty place between the first and the third.

How to put the vacant position to empty

Let it not empty.

I set the height of the `EditText` to 0, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this will remove the empty space

Answer (score 0):

use `View.setVisibility(View.GONE);` this should make the work

Answer (score 0):

You should use `editText.setVisibility(View.GONE)` View.INVISIBLE only hide element but remain place for him.